# Auto-delete messages sent in a specific channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was curious if anyone could help me out here.

My bot has a suggestions channel, for the players to provide suggestions to make the server better.
However, it gets clustered because they chat. I was curious if there was a way to delete any message in the specific channel, except bot commands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can check if the message starts with your prefix or has been sent by a bot: if none of those, it means it's not a command nor a command response. All of that assuming the message is in that channel.

```js
// ASSUMPTIONS:
// channel = your channel as a TextChannel
// prefix = your prefix as a string
// owner = you as a User

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel != channel || msg.author.bot || msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
  else msg.delete();
});

// if you want your messages to be ignored too:
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.channel != channel || msg.author.bot || msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author == owner) return;
  else msg.delete();
});
```

Comment: I can't help you if I don't know how you did it :/ Have you replaced my sample values with your actual ones? Does it print any error?

Comment: Oops! Probably should’ve thought about that. Yes I changed Prefix to `!` and channel to the actual channel ID. It does not print an error.

Comment: Gotcha: you're using an ID instead of the actual channel object. It doesn't return any error because we told it to ignore the message if `message.channel != channel`. You can fix that by saying `let channel = message.guild.channel.get("CHANNEL_ID_HERE_AS_A_STRING");`. This should fix your problem ;)

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. I keep getting this issue:
`(node:1504) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\grant\Desktop\Bots\pausebot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (C:\Users\grant\Desktop\Bots\pausebot\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)`

Comment: It may be caused by the fact that you declared `schannel` outside of the `message` event listener. Try moving those first two lines inside `bot.on('message', ...)`

Comment: Happy to hear that :)